# How can you set the SMTP envelope MAIL FROM in AIX 6.1 Sendmail?

Tags: linux, email, sendmail, aix

We have new SMTP relay host and it requires that the sender's email address should be the company's official email domain instead of server hostname

Already did masquerade using generetics table. However, the new relay host still rejected my test email. It seems that my configuration still using server hostname. I am thinking that the MAIL FROM in sendmail SMTP envelope is still the server hostname.

Config Done:

1. #uncomment line in /etc/sendmail.cf

   Kgenerics hash -o /etc/mail/genericstable
2. Create genericstable file in /etc/mail directory

   a. Set IDs and the addresses I need to map

   b. Convert the genericstable file into a db file

Still I got this error message from the relay host:

*Reason:[{504 5.5.2 sender@AIXServername Sender address rejected: need fully-qualified address*

Comment: For the benefit of other users. I found the answer in this link.

https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/aix-43/sendmail-changing-from-addr-and-reply-addr-4175519189/